# Why does one need to login into the Azure Container registry before pulling the images from it, i.e. az login is not good enough?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I am already logged in into Azure through `az login`, however in order to pull images from an ACR I had to also run `az acr login` - I was not even asked for credentials, because the same account is used.

I do not understand why is `az login` not good enough?

Comment: I can only guess, but it looks like the [acr token is valid for 3 hours and does not auto refresh like the one you get with az login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#individual-login-with-azure-ad). So it must be to force a little more security.

Comment: But then why does the Azure Container Registry get this special treatment?

Comment: I looked at azure feedback and did not find anything. Acr login should suffice. May I suggest you post this to azure feedback?

Comment: @LMGagne - do you mean `az login` should suffice?

Comment: Yes. I do not know of any other resources using the az CLI that requires another login to work. The usage should be consistent for all resources and commands.

Comment: @LMGagne it is clearly by design (see link I posted).

Comment: @Crowcoder Agreed. However, this statement would be true for any other resources manageable using the CLI. Why is security of ACR more important than AAD, SQL, storage, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik `az acr login` actually does perform a `docker login` with your local docker runtime under the hood. As your docker runtime does not know anything about Azure, just `az login` does not suffice. You could do the same manually be getting the credentials from your ACR and then run `docker login my.azurecr.io --username my --password xxx`

`az acr login` is not required to work with the ACR resource, but only with the registry from a docker perspective, such as pulling or pushing images.